# MVC4 issue with showing multiple partial views on a single View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been struggling with this problem to no avail. Using MVC4 I have 3 models I wish to show on a single view via partial views.  The Single View is comprised of 3 partial views (3 numerated list tables). I can get one model to display in the view, but can't figure out how to display the other 2.

Here is what I have for The View Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        //Database.SetInitializer<AlertsContext>(null);
        Database.SetInitializer<MemberUsersContext>(null);
        //Database.SetInitializer<ClubsContext>(null);

        //AlertsContext db = new AlertsContext();
       MemberUsersContext db = new MemberUsersContext();
        //ClubsContext db = new ClubsContext();
        //db.MemberUsers.ToList()
        return View(db.MemberUsers.ToList());
    }
```

This is what I have as the model for the View itself (to compile I remove the two that aren't under the @model IENumerable statement:

```
    @model IEnumerable<GMC.Models.MemberUsers>

    <div class="dashboard_alerts">    
      @Html.Partial("DashboardAlerts")
   </div>

    <div class="dashboard_pending_clubs">    
       @Html.Partial("DashboardClubs")
    </div>

    <div class="dashboard_verified_members">    
       @Html.Partial("DashboardMembers")
     </div>
```

In each partial View the headers are as follows:

DashboardClubs

```
    @model IEnumerable<GMC.Models.Clubs>
```

DashboardMembers

```
    @model IEnumerable<GMC.Models.MemberUsers>
```

DashboardAlerts

```
    @model IEnumerable<GMC.Models.Alerts>
```

Now my question is how do I pass the three database contexts into the Dashboard? I am thoroughly confused and am struggling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of ways you could do this and make it generic, but they will mostly all have a ViewModel.  A class you create specifically to support your Dashboard view:

```
public class DashboardViewModel {   
  public IEnumerable<GMC.Models.Clubs> Clubs {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<GMC.Models.MemberUsers> MemberUsers {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<GMC.Models.Alerts> Alerts {get;set;}
}
```

If these are just different tables in a database, they should all be accessed through the same context, because the context manages your connection and other resources.  However, without seeing that code I will not go on that tangent.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        //populate data into our view model(vm)
        var vm = new DashboardViewModel{
           Clubs = db.Clubs.ToList(),
           MemberUsers = db.MemberUsers.ToList(),
           Alerts = db.Alerts.ToList()
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
```

Dashboard view:

```
    @model DashboardViewModel

    <div class="dashboard_alerts">    
      @Html.Partial("DashboardAlerts", Model.Alerts)
   </div>

    <div class="dashboard_pending_clubs">    
       @Html.Partial("DashboardClubs", Model.Clubs)
    </div>

    <div class="dashboard_verified_members">    
       @Html.Partial("DashboardMembers", Model.MemberUsers)
     </div>
```

Personally, instead of using Html.Partial I would use Action/RenderAction, as these will allow you to actually call another action that returns a PartialViewResult, and thus each action is responsible for retrieving its own data.  I don't always do it this way, but if it is appropriate, then the action/partial view is more reusable that way.

This would look more like this:

```
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult Clubs()
    {
       ....
        return PartialView(db.Clubs.ToList());//this assumes the partial view is named Clubs.cshtml, otherwise you'll need to use the overload where you pass the view name
    }

    public PartialViewResult Alerts()
    {
       ....
        return PartialView(db.Alerts.ToList());
    }
```

...

Dashboard.cshtml

```
    <div class="dashboard_alerts">    
      @Html.Action("Alerts")
   </div>

    <div class="dashboard_pending_clubs">    
       @Html.Action("Clubs")
    </div>

    <div class="dashboard_verified_members">    
       @Html.Action("Members")
     </div>
```

Comment: both of your answers seemed to work, but i went the second route. very clean, very awesome. +100 if I could.

Comment: What exactly does Action do as opposed to RenderPartial and Partial? I should know this. But ASP.NET MVC4 is relatively new to me.

Comment: @AmitApollo .Partial() will use the Clubs.cshtml directly, so you have to pass the model data to it as I did in the second parameter.  .Action() instead will call an action method, and that action can do whatever is needed to query for data and pass it to `return Partial(myDataHere)`.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a ViewModel specific for the Dashboard page.

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<GMC.Models.Clubs> Clubs { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<GMC.Models.MemberUsers> Users  { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<GMC.Models.Alerts> Alerts  { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the Dashboard action method, you would populate each list:

```
myModel.Users = db.MemberUsers.ToList();
...
```

You would then need to update the view to take in this new ViewModel

```
 @model DashboardViewModel
```

Finally, from within the view, you would need to pass in the data to each partial:

```
@Html.Partial("DashboardAlerts", Model.Alerts)

@Html.Partial("DashboardClubs", Model.Clubs)
```

Comment: This works, too. I just went with AaronLS's second solution, but +1 regardless.